# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. WITHOUT STATE

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

Let's pretend for a little while that I know what the error means and when usually originates but now I have no idea what react complains on.

Error comes from this simple component:

```
export interface PostHandlerOutProps {
  posts: PostFragment[];
}

export interface PostHandlerProps {
  children: (outProps: PostHandlerOutProps) => ReactNode;
  initialPosts?: PostHandlerOutProps['posts'];
}

const PostsHandler: FC<PostHandlerProps> = ({ children, initialPosts = [] }) => {
  const { data } = useQuery<PostsQuery, PostsQueryVariables>(postsQuery);

  return <>{children({ posts: data?.posts || initialPosts })}</>;
};
```

here is how the component is used:

```
export interface PostsProps {
  initialPosts: PostFragment[];
}

const Posts: FC<PostsProps> = ({ initialPosts }) => {
  return (
      <PostsHandler initialPosts={initialPosts}>
        {({ posts }) => (
          <div>For simplicity sake nothing but I am still getting the error.</div>
        )}
      </PostsHandler>
  );
};
```

And still randomly I am getting this error:

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    at PostsHandler (webpack-internal:///./src/components/post/PostsHandler.tsx:20:3)
    at Posts (webpack-internal:///./src/views/admin/Posts.tsx:18:3)
```

Does anybody knows what is going on here? And is it something I should concern about?

*Just for explanation. I need this architecture because initialPosts comes from server side rendering which I need on the client side replace for the same data but from useQuery because it gives me ability to react on mutation's apollo cache updates.*

Comment: it is saying `PostsHandler.tsx` is unmounted, maybe you are using state in that component

Comment: No, you can see that in `PostsHandler.tsx` is no state. There is only hook `useQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems that I managed identify the problem which is Apollo hook `useQuery`. Since 2019 developers complains on this issue and now it seems that Apollo team will finally resolve it. According to this post: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/7404#issuecomment-776142370 -
They will silent the warning. Bravo Apollo team!